# Is it a bad idea to take my cat on to the lake on the weekends?

Tags: anxiety

My family has a lake house 25 minutes away and my cat absolutely loves being there. I can only go on the weekends with my job and with his food issues I have to feed him a very specific way so I can’t leave him home alone. Would it be a bad idea to take him every Friday morning and stay until Monday? He is 10 years old and doesn’t have anxiety just food allergies and a bad back. I am also getting ready to take him to college and I was thinking if this was okay he would get used to change. What do you think?

Comment: Are you letting him outdoors at the lake? Note: There is (in my opinion) no wrong answer to that question.

Comment: We used to take our cat to the beach. He loved it. Unless you're worried about him picking up some disease or running away, I won't expect there to be any issues. // That said: If your cat has never been anywhere but your house, please be aware that is will be quite a shock for him, so bring some soothing herbs to help him relax, and maybe a couple familiar blankets that smell like home, which you can cover him with if he panics.

Comment: the only one that can answer your question is your cat,all i can do is to give you my opinion.you can often find ticks close to water so you should protect him against this and treat him against intestinal parasites(some spot on products do treat against both ticks and worms at the same time).

Answer (score 2):

Kitty carriers are a very good idea when traveling. Cats can fail to understand the dangers of cars and such.

If you are keeping kitty indoors, and he's happy with the trip and the other house, then there would seem to be no problem moving him. If he's happy with it, it is unlikely there would be any health effects. It's only if he was freaked out by it or seemed to be stressed by the trip. You should keep an eye on him and give him some extra attention associated with the travel so he associates it with happiness.

If you are letting him outdoors, be sure to check with your vet that all his shots are up to date, including for sure rabies and anti-tick treatment. Make sure he has a collar with tags that show where he belongs, or an ID chip. Or both.

Comment: I just wanted to add that sometimes cats show stress in subtle ways or ways you don't really expect. Excessive shedding or unusual kneading can both be signs of stress for example. Cats can also be showing signs of stress while also showing positive body language, for example, the tail could be held straight up, which is confident body language. So be careful to pay close attention to your cat.